# How to use React-i18next library with tailwind css and links without breaking sentence into parts

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-i18next

I have with problem with multi language translation using useTransalate.

When I have on a page a typical content like this:
"By continuing, you agree to Terms and Conditions and accept Privacy Policy."
I need that "Terms and Conditions" and "Privacy Policy" will be in links and in different colour.
So the easiest way it to do this:

en.json

```
  "signup_you_agree": "By continuing, you agree to",
  "signup_terms_conditions": "Terms and Conditions",
  "signup_accept": "and accept",
  "signup_privacy": "Privacy Policy",
```

index.tsx

```
             <>
              <p className="font-light text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-300">
                {t('signup_you_agree')}{' '}
                <a
                  href="..."
                  className="font-medium text-primary-600 dark:text-primary-500 hover:underline"
                >
                  {t('signup_terms_conditions')}
                </a>{' '}
                {t('signup_accept')}{' '}
                <a
                  href="..."
                  className="font-medium text-primary-600 dark:text-primary-500 hover:underline"
                >
                  {t('signup_privacy')}
                </a>
                .
              </p>
            </>
```

But...
To prevent problem with translations when sentence has breaks I need it to be more like this.

```
"signup_terms_privacy": "By continuing, you agree to <a href="...">Terms and Conditions</a> and accept <a href="...">Privacy Policy</a>."
```

Is there any way to it? Adding tailwind css and links to text from translation?

DangerouslySetInnerHTML is dangerous and it wont accept tailwind css or mui. I was looking for some extension for react-i18next but could find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do that is using Trans Component from react-i18next.

It would look like:

```
          <Trans
            i18nKey="signup_terms_privacy"
            components={{
              1: (
                <a
                  href="..."
                  className="font-medium text-primary-600 dark:text-primary-500 hover:underline"
                />
              ),
              2: (
                <a
                  href="..."
                  className="font-medium text-primary-600 dark:text-primary-500 hover:underline"
                />
              )
            }}
          />
```

With en.json

```
"signup_terms_privacy": "By continuing, you agree to <1>Terms and Conditions</1> and accept <2>Privacy Policy</2>."
```